# Untouchable File on Linux Server, Even Though Permission == 777

Tags: permissions, webserver

I have a file on my web server that I can't rename, delete, move, edit, anything. I have set the permissions to 777. What else can I do?

**EDIT:** to clarify - this is on a hosting service to which I do not have shell access. The file is a Drupal installation's settings.php.

**SOLUTION:** Directory file permissions were inaccurate. Thanks to whomever suggested checking that.

Comment: How about posting some more information? What's the output of "ls -la file"? What error message do you get? What file are we talking about?

Comment: Also check the permissions on the directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check extended attributes, if applicable:

```
# lsattr file
----i-------------- file
# chattr -i file
```

The 'i' bit is 'immutable', meaning it resists all changes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that its one of those annoying `.pureftp-upload` files. Even if it isn't, there are 2 ways I usually deal with these files.

- Use your file manager from within your web hosting control panel (probably CPanel).
- Try using PHP (replace the pureftp-upload filename with your filename):

```
$f = ".pureftp-upload.23kjfvds9osd890235mn";
unlink($f);
```

then surround the above code with `<?php` at the beginning and `?>` at the end (code formatting doesn't play nice with php tags).

Answer (score 0):

> What else can I do?

- tell us what OS/distro you are running
- If it is Linux, check if SELinux or Apparmor are running
- If SELinux is running, what is the output of `"ls -lZ file"`?
- use unlink to delete the file instead of rm
- use `ls -i` to show the inode of the file and try to remove it by inode number

Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

If this file is in a folder deemed to be accessible through Apache web service, you may need to stop Apache for a moment then do your changes.

I know IIS in windows has something like this where if the file could possibly be accessed then the user rights don't matter.